# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'F' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
`$data['top_argo'] = \DB::select( \DB::raw('select DISTINCT SUM(transaction.total) as total_argo, COUNT(transaction.id) as total_trans, users.name FROM transaction LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER ON customer.id = transaction.id_driver_fk LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = customer.id_user_fk WHERE id_customer_fk IS NOT NULL AND transaction.status = 'F' GROUP B`Y users.name   ORDER BY SUM (transaction.total) DESC LIMIT 10'));
```

I need to run this query on my laravel, but I got an error like I said on the title. I'm new to laravel so can you help me?

Comment: You might need to use IDE for a start and take a look at string concatenation. Those error message indicate unexpected string on your query.

Comment: Change GROUP B`Y users.name to GROUP BY users.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the exception replace `'F'` with `\'F\'`

Answer (score 1):

Your query has lots of syntax errors. Don`t use double quotes without binding it a string.

```
data['top_argo'] = \DB::select( \DB::raw("select DISTINCT SUM(transaction.total)
 as total_argo, COUNT(transaction.id) as total_trans, users.name FROM transaction 
 LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER ON customer.id = transaction.id_driver_fk 
 LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = customer.id_user_fk 
 WHERE id_customer_fk IS NOT NULL AND transaction.status = 'F' GROUP BY users.name ORDER BY SUM (transaction.total) DESC LIMIT 10"));
```